# Browser REST Client ask for credential and it fails for RESTEasy Service

Tags: java, resteasy, spring-security-oauth2

I have created one RESTEasy service in java using Spring security Oauth2 for the authentication and token generate. Every  thing is working fine for me but when I trying to access my service to generate the token from the browser REST Client it ask for credential and it fails but at the same time if I access the same service by HTTPClient in Java it work for me,

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:80/my-rest-application/oauth/token");

          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id","myclientid"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret","myclientsecret"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","someuser"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","somepassword"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","password"));

          post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Http client in java work for me but in browser rest client it ask for credential and returns bad request
[image: browser rest client response]

Any idea why it happens?

my configuration,

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetails" class="my own client details implementation"/>



<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" /> -->
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Logs ? The content-length of your response is 1061 bytes. What does it contain ? Also what is the content-type of your *request* when using your rest client ?

Comment: my content-type is application/json

Comment: That does not sound right, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now with the content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: I will create the comment as a response so you can mark the issue resolved (this is good for your Karma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `content-type` on the REST client to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`